# Install openstack on vm windows azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I just installed Openstack on Windows azure virtual machine.
But basicly Openstack need fixed ip(ip address which used to communicate between vm and openstack) and float ip(which used to communicate vm and network outside or internet)

But on windows Azure, VM just gave one private ip and one public ip for my azure virtual machine which i've installed Openstack.

So that VM which i created using openstack can't get both of fixed ip and float ip.

How i can configure this on windows azure vm so that my vm which i created using openstack can get fixed and float ip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot get around IP limitations that your VM gets from Azure. However that being said, depending on what O/S you run, you have always options to introduce more IP-addresses at O/S level.

Now depending of the O/S you can bridge/tunnel those IP addresses to access that VM in a manner that those IPs are exposed to clients. VPN is one good example of such functionality - which you may use different tools (again specific details rely on the O/S).

This is the only solution that comes to my mind; I've faced (and dealt with) the Azure only-one-IP limitation on other scenarios...